# How to add a wait function till a button is pressed?

Tags: java, android, button, onclicklistener

I want to add a wait till, `Button` (Enter) is pressed function to my code But i am still new to this.
I know there are some errors in my code I was playing around with it, But what I want to do is when I press the **line** `Button` I want it to display Input X,Y,Z then wait till enter is pressed to execute the rest of my code I want to add in. How would I implement something like this in my code?

Here is my `MainActivity` Class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button enter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enter);
    Button line = (Button) findViewById(R.id.line);
    Button arc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.arc);

    line.setOnClickListener(this);
    enter.setOnClickListener(this);
    arc.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TextView vector = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.point);
    TextView index = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.index);
    TextView info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
    EditText cl = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    DrawingUtils call = new DrawingUtils();
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.line:
        info.setText("Input X,Y,Z");
        // This Is Where the Wait Function Will GO
        vector.setText(call.addVertice());
        index.setText("1");

        break;
    case R.id.enter:
        String In = cl.getText().toString();
        call.setInputCoords(In);
        break;
    case R.id.arc:
        info.setText("Enter Vertice1 ");
        // Code for entering Vertice1(Also has wait function)
        info.setText("Enter Vertice2");
        // Code for entering Vertice2(Also has wait function)
        info.setText("Enter Height");
        //Code for entering Height(Also has wait function)

    }

}
```

}

Here is my `DrawingUtils` Class:

```
public class DrawingUtils {
String inputCoords;
String[] vertice;

public String getInputCoords() {
    return inputCoords;
}

public void setInputCoords(String inputCoords) {
    this.inputCoords = inputCoords;
}

public String addVertice() {
    int i = 0;
    vertice = inputCoords.split(",");
    return vertice[i];

}
```

}

Comment: Maybe execute your code on enter key press...

Comment: In your code above, when the line button is pressed, the "info" TextView will change to "Input X,Y,Z". Then, nothing will happen until the enter button is pressed and `String In = cl.getText().toString(); call.setInputCoords(In);` will execute. Is this not what you want?

Comment: Why dont you execute your required code in onClick of your enter button. I guess then there is no need to wait.

Comment: Cant has to be executed from Line. I will be adding other Buttons such as Arc and PolyLine to my App. All i want the Enter Button to do is enter the floats.

Comment: It's still not clear to me what the problem is. Is the code erroring?

Comment: No no Hold on one sec and ill edit the above code to better explain my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* this is what you are after. Apologies if not!

Use a boolean flag to handle state within your app. This way you can execute different code if something has happened.

```
boolean enterPressed = false;    

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    TextView vector = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.point);
    TextView index = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.index);
    TextView info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
    EditText cl = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    DrawingUtils call = new DrawingUtils();
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.line:
        if (enterPressed) {
            vector.setText(call.addVertice());
            index.setText("1");
        }
        else {
            info.setText("Input X,Y,Z");
        }

        break;
    case R.id.enter:
        String In = cl.getText().toString();
        call.setInputCoords(In);
        enterPressed = true;
        break;
    case R.id.arc:
        info.setText("Enter Vertice1 ");
        // Code for entering Vertice1
        info.setText("Enter Vertice2");
        // Code for entering Vertice2

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you I think this may work if i can put a switch statement in the else and get the ids for the buttons it would diffently give me the flexablity to execute codes for the other buttons, but like arc has three things to enter thats the part that i think is going to give me the trouble.